# How to avoid insertion of a row of data based on a column value within the same date range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am inserting data to a sheet from user inputs. Before inserting I want to make sure that there is already a row having same email address (column 3, value e + k3 in the code) within the given date range. If it is already there, it will not insert that row but will process other inputs. How to solve it? Thanks to Tanaike.

```
function onePeriodm(){
  
  const srcSheetName = "Dashboard";
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [[,,,,,k3],,[f5,g5,...h5i5j5k5]] = srcSheet.getRange("F3:K5").getDisplayValues();
  
  // 2. Convert the values for putting to the destination sheet.
  const dstValues = h5i5j5k5.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e != "") ar.push([g5, Number(e), e + k3, , , f5]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // 3. Put the converted values to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(f5);
  const dstCurrentValues = dstSheet.getRange(`A2:A${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const index = dstCurrentValues.lastIndexOf(dstValues[0][0]) + 2;
  dstSheet.insertRowsAfter(index, dstValues.length);
  dstSheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

[image]

Comment: where's the "given date range"?  Naming the variables `k3`, `f5`, etc may seem helpful when the sheet is visible to you, but consider giving them meaningful names like "emailAddress" for those who can only see the JavaScript.

Comment: Please check the image attached now. The date range is based on the user input in G5 cell of Dashboard sheet and then need to check in the destination sheet for any duplication using column value 3 (umail, H5/I5/J5/K5 + k3). Hope you got it

Comment: It is working but insertion of row is happening after the first row of that date range. It should be after the last row of the date range. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `reduce` function so you will not generate a new row when the existing data set already has a row with the input date and student ID.

This requires you shift up where you get the current values to step #2 and expand what values you retrieve to include the email column so you can access those values in the `reduce` function.  We also can't use the `.flat()` trick now since we are looking at multiple columns, but that's fine because we have `.find()` and `.map()` that will work just as well.

Now the `reduce` becomes step #3, and we add in our requirement.  We use `.find()` to try and get the an existing record with the given date and student email.  `find` returns `undefined` if it fails, so we can update our `reduce` condition to only push from just `studentId != ""` to `studentId != "" && !existingEntry`.

Because we changed the shape of `dstCurrentValues` to expand it and get email values, we need to change `.flat()` to `.map(row => row[0])` to achieve the same shape for `lastIndexOf`.

*For the  benefit of all readers, the variable names have been updated from "A1" notation to names that reflect the values they contain.*

```js
function onePeriodm() {
  const srcSheetName = "Dashboard";

  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [
    [, , , , , emailPattern],
    ,
    [courseCatalogId, dateString, ...studentIds],
  ] = srcSheet.getRange("F3:K5").getDisplayValues();

  // 2. Retrieve current values
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(courseCatalogId);
  const dstCurrentValues = dstSheet
    .getRange(`A2:C${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`) // expanded to include email column
    .getDisplayValues(); // not flattening since we have multiple columns now

  // 3. Convert the values for putting to the destination sheet.
  //    Do not include if there is already an email for this date in current values
  const dstValues = studentIds.reduce((array, studentId) => {
    const existingEntry = dstCurrentValues.find(
      (row) => row[0] === dateString && row[2] === studentId + emailPattern
    );
    if (studentId != "" && !existingEntry)
      array.push([
        dateString,
        Number(studentId),
        studentId + emailPattern,
        ,
        ,
        courseCatalogId,
      ]);
    return array;
  }, []);

  // 4. Put the converted values to the destination sheet.
  const index = dstCurrentValues.map((row) => row[0]).lastIndexOf(dateString);
  const row = index + 2;
  dstSheet.insertRowsAfter(row, dstValues.length);
  dstSheet
    .getRange(row + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length)
    .setValues(dstValues);
}
```

Comment: It is working but insertion of row is happening after the first row of the date range. It should be after the last row of the date range. Please check it.

Comment: @AktaruzzamanLiton - ah, yes, I ignored the obvious importance of "last" in `lastIndexOf` - lol.  I restored `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: Yes it is working fine now. If I want to put all the 4 set of Student IDs in the beginning like F5, G5, H5, I5 and Subject and Date in J5, K5 respectively, Is it possible to implement. I tried before but it shows error saying REST element should be at the end. Could you advise me how to solve it if is simple.

Comment: @AktaruzzamanLiton - I'm not sure if I understand.  It would preferable if you update your question or ask a new question.  When you [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the arrays, you have to keep the `...` at the end of any particular array and without a trailing comma.  After assignment, you can reorder however you wish, including [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the student IDs into a new array.

Comment: could you please check my recent post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63743728/how-to-create-dynamic-map-or-links-using-range-of-latitude-and-longitude-values